# permanent powertop changes with systemctl

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, systemd

I have got a .sh-script, trying to make powertop changes permanent.

```
'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control';
```

the commands in this .sh-script are all of this type.

I have a systemd-service in /etc/systemd/system with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/my_username/.autostart_sudo.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script ".autostart_sudo.sh" is called correctly after boot, (for example "bluetooth off"-command in this file is called perfeclty) but the echo->-commands are not called successfully.

I noticed that typing

```
  sudo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control';
```

in a terminal gives a restriction-error,
but

```
  sudo su
 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control';
```

works.

how do I have to change my systemd+bash-script to get the powertop-changes working on boot?

Thanks in advance!

### Edit:

Okay, I try to describe the flow again:
I got the systemd service posted on top of this post.
This service calls the ".autostart_sudo.sh" in my /home/user/.

There are plenty commands in this .autostart_sudo.sh looking like this:

```
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.0/power/control';
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.3/power/control';
(...)
thinkfan start
```

The "thinkfan start" needs also root-privileges to start correctly, this one works, but the "echo"-commands dont.

I also tryed

```
bash -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control;'
bash -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.7/power/control;'
bash -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.2/power/control;'
bash -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control;'
bash -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control;'
```

doesnt work either :/

The sudo-test-stuff I mentioned above were just tests *in a Terminal*.

any advice?

Comment: Do you actually have `'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control'` in your script or `echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control'`? In any case, if your script is called by systemd, `sudo` should not be necessary. Dows it work if you just `echo` the commands into the files, with no `sudo`?

Comment: no, the sudo-test was outside the script in a terminal.
i have the systemd-service calling the script, where the "echo..."-commands are listed (without sudo).

Comment: Still not sure I understand, could you give us the whole picture? What sudo test, I thought systemd was running this at startup? Could you maybe post the script? Or at least a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: i tryed to make things more clear in my post-edit :-)

Comment: Does `echo 'auto' | sudo tee 'file'` work?

Comment: About the `sudo` test in the terminal: `sudo echo` has root privileges, while redirection `>` is performed with the shell's privileges (since it is done by the shell, not by echo). That's why the redirection works after `sudo su` - su opens a privileged shell.

Comment: @ignis `echo 'auto' | sudo tee 'file'` works in Terminal, but not in the .sh called by systemd :-/
Any other suggestions? It has to be something with root-privileges...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that X-bit set for /home/my_username/.autostart_sudo.sh
Keep in the mind that owner uid/gid of this script must be root to prevent shell code injection by malware.
And

```
sudo echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control';
```

won't work because '>' executed not by root. Try

```
sudo bash -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.1/power/control';
```

Comment: i tryed to make things more clear in my post-edit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, my bad.
I called `tlp start` after the Powertop-tweaks.
Dint know that tlp would mess the settings up this bad.
So, if you have the same problem:
call `tlp start`

Comment: Well done for figuring it out. Could you give a bit more detail please? When were you calling `tlp start` before and when are you calling it now?

Answer (score 0):

So sad, finally I have to step in and answer this question...

*Earlier I wasn't able to answer as I didn't have the reputation to answer questions, comment, upvote. So, if you want more answers then do upvote this answer*

You have to do 2 things:

> 1) Automate giving password to every command requiring sudo privileges.

```
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S COMMAND
```

> 2) Give permissions to everyone to change content of each configuration file

```
chmod 666 File_Path
```

here is the code which works for me:

**Change "PASSWORD" with your current account sudo password**

```
#For File Permission Change

echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-5/device/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1.6/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.2/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/power/control'
echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -S chmod 666 '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.4/power/control'

#For Actual Modification

echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy'
echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy'
echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-5/device/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1.6/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.2/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/power/control'
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.4/power
```

**Note: you may have to change the whole commands as per your system :)**

Comment: As long as you aren’t banned or suspended, you always have permission to answer any question (that isn’t locked or protected).

Comment: Anyway, did my new code work for you?